# Transform result of a query nxn into columns - ORACLE

Tags: oracle, plsql, pivot

I have faced a problem and I don't know how to solve it.

I have the following structure:

- Table PIECE
- Table PIECE_CHARACTHERISTIC
- Table CHARACTERISTIC

The table PIECE_CHARACTHERISTIC makes the relationship NxN between PIECE and CHARACTERISTIC.

So, one Piece can have many characteristics.
I need to take some of these characteristcs and show them as a column in a query result:

```
SELECT PC.CHARACTERISTIC_ID, PC.CHAR_VALUE FROM PIECE P
INNER JOIN PIECE_CHARACTHERISTIC PC ON P.PIECE_ID = PC.PIECE_ID
WHERE 
    PC.CHARACTERISTIC_ID = 1 OR
    PC.CHARACTERISTIC_ID = 2 OR
    PC.CHARACTERISTIC_ID = 3;
```

As result of this query I have something like this:

```
PIECE     CHARACTERISTIC_ID    CHAR_VALUE
  P1              1                A
  P1              2                B
  P1              3                C
  P2              1                D
  P2              2                E
  P3              1                X
  ...
```

I would like the result to be like this:

```
PIECE     CHAR_1     CHAR_2   CHAR_3
 P1         A          B        C
 P2         D          E        NULL
 P3         X          NULL     NULL
```

Resuming, I would like to transform the result of a column of characteristics in many columns with the value of each characteristic for the piece.
Thank you very much for your help!!

Answer (score 0):

this should work, you only need to add Left Joins for every column of characteristics

```
SELECT 
     P.PIECE_ID, 
     PC1.CHAR_VALUE AS CHAR_1, 
     PC2.CHAR_VALUE AS CHAR_2, 
     PC3.CHAR_VALUE AS CHAR_3
FROM PIECE P 
LEFT JOIN PIECE_CHARACTHERISTIC PC1
ON PC1.PIECE_ID = P.PIECE_ID AND PC1.CHARACTERISTIC_ID = 1
LEFT JOIN PIECE_CHARACTHERISTIC PC2
ON PC2.PIECE_ID = P.PIECE_ID AND PC1.CHARACTERISTIC_ID = 2
LEFT JOIN PIECE_CHARACTHERISTIC PC3
ON PC3.PIECE_ID = P.PIECE_ID AND PC1.CHARACTERISTIC_ID = 3
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this. It's a little bit ugly, but should work.

```
with
A as ( 
    select PIECE, listagg(CHAR_VALUE,'|') within group (order by CHAR_VALUE) TXT
    from 
        PIECE P, PIECE_CHARACTHERISTIC PC
    where     
        P.PIECE_ID = PC.PIECE_ID
    group by PIECE
)
select
    A.PIECE,
    substr(A.TXT, 1, 1) CHAR_1,
    substr(A.TXT, 3, 1) CHAR_2, 
    substr(A.TXT, 5, 1) CHAR_3
from A
```